# HttpClient and blocking PostAsync

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I know it is a popular C# question. However I think my question is specific.
I plan to do two requests to the web server. First request is a long GET. The webserver does not reply immediately, wait and keep C# client connected. At the same time in another Task I'm doing POST request.

Problem: if I set same cookies (PHPSESSION) as the first request, `PostAsync` blocks and wait for the completion of the first request. It does not block if there are no cookies (!), but this makes no sense.

What I tried:

- Use `SendAsync` and `HttpRequestMessage` for each request
- Create new `HttpClient` and copy cookies.
- Set `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(url)).ConnectionLimit`
- Tried to add random cookie to the second request

C# .NET 4.7.2

Question: How to add more parallelism?

Update: I'd like to confirm: **`PostAsync` and `SendAsync` don't block without cookies.** If I copy cookies from long GET, the requests are blocked and waiting for the completion of the GET. If I interrupt long GET, Post and Send completing successfully immediately.

Comment: So the website is successfully preventing you from interrupting an in-flight GET with a rogue POST in the same session?

Comment: Post your code. The description is unclear. PostAsync doesn't block. HttpClient is thread-safe. If the *server* throttles requests for the same session identifies by cookies, there's nothing you can do

Comment: There was [a bug in .NET Framework 4.7.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/main/releases/net471/KnownIssues/534719-Networking.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit%20default%20behavior%20changed.md) that limited concurrent connections to a single server to 2 but that was fixed since and besides, the question says only one concurrent request is active. Are you sure the *runtime* where this happens is 4.7.2? Are there no other requests active beyond the 2 you mentioned?

Comment: GSerg, thank you for attention to my post. I don't want to interrupt. I want the component to open another connection.
If I interrupt long GET, PostAsync completes immediately.

Comment: Seems to be a problem on the server side not on your client side. I would guess the server doesn't answer your post request until the get is finished. So there is nothing to fix in your http client, but on your server.

Comment: Oliver, I reduced the code to very simple .php and .cs. I clearly see that problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is being caused by a mechanism on the PHP backend known as session locking, which limits execution of any script to one per session ID. This is to prevent concurrency issues within the same user session.

If you control the backend, you can call [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) early-on in the execution of the script in order to free up additional requests within the same session.

If you *don't* control the backend, then your only option is to create a new session.

Note that session locking will apply on all requests under a given session, even if sent from different browsers, hosts, or even networks.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! Yes, this is the answer!
I think I need to use Fiddler earlier to see if request reach the server ...
Unfortunately I can't upvote it, hope others will do.

Comment: @Petr Yes you can, just like you can mark this answer as correct.